# Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non- object error

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to perform a calculation which checks to see if a date is in between two other dates using an if statement with the dates in the correct format but I still seem to be getting a timestamp error.  Any help as to how I can fix it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$Query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblrental WHERE `CARID` = '".$Car."'");
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query);
$ARTakeOut = $row3\['TakeOutDate'\];
$ARReturn = $row3\['ReturnDate'\];
$ARDaysRented = $row3\['DaysRented'\];
$ARDaysRented = (round($ARDaysRented/2));
$MidDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ARTakeOut . ' + '.$ARDaysRented.' days'));

echo $MidDate; ?> <br> <?PHP
echo $ARTakeOut; ?> <br> <?PHP
echo $ARReturn; ?> <br> <?PHP




if (
  $MidDate->getTimestamp() > $ARTakeOut->getTimestamp() && 
  $MidDate->getTimestamp() < $ARReturn->getTimestamp()){
  echo "is between";
}else{
   echo "NO GO!";  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why all these escape `\` chars in your code? Was that just because you were trying to wrap all the code in a link?

Comment: `date()` does not return an object!!! Look at the `DateTime` class in PHP Manual

Comment: Do you mean in the Query? The `` on each side of CARID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$MidDate`, `$ARTakeOut` and `$ARReturn` are all strings (`$MidDate` being the output of [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and the others being from a database read), not `DateTime` objects. You need to make them into `DateTime` objects instead if you want to use `getTimeStamp`:

```
$ARTakeOut = new DateTime($row3['TakeOutDate']);
$ARReturn = new DateTime($row3['ReturnDate']);
$ARDaysRented = $row3['DaysRented'];
$ARDaysRented = (round($ARDaysRented/2));
$MidDate = clone $ARTakeOut;
$MidDate->modify("+ $ARDaysRented days");

echo $MidDate->format('Y-m-d'); ?> <br> <?PHP
echo $ARTakeOut->format('Y-m-d'); ?> <br> <?PHP
echo $ARReturn->format('Y-m-d'); ?> <br> <?PHP
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Oc6QK)

Note I have removed the superfluous `\` before your `[` and `]`s